# How can I default an ancestral relationship with cancan to an internal node of the tree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I am using [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) to authorize my controller actions.  One of classes where access is authorized by cancan is a tree, implemented with [acts_as_ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry).  I'm having problems using `load_and_authorize_resource` when the user is not permitted to access the root level, but rather is allowed access starting at an interior node.

Here are some relavant class definitions:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization, :inverse_of => :users
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization, :inverse_of => :posts
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry :cache_depth => true
  has_many :users, :inverse_of => :organization
  has_many :posts, :inverse_of => :organization
end
```

The rules for managing posts are "You can manage posts in any organization below yours".  My cancan abilities definition is this:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new 

    # subtree_ids is added by acts_as_ancestry
    can :manage, Post, {:organization_id => user.organization.subtree_ids}
  end
end
```

In the controller, I have this (other actions omitted)

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :post

  def index
  end

  def new
  end
end
```

Everything works fine when the authorized user belongs to the root organization. However, when I login as a user authorized at an internal node, the index action works fine, but when the new action is invoked, I get a can-can authorization error.

Here is what I see in the log:

```
Access denied on new #<Post id: nil, organization_id: 1>
```

The `organization_id 1` (the root) is coming from the schema:

```
create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "organization_id", :default => 1
end
```

With cancan, the new action will build a new `Post` and assign it to `@post`.  When it does this, it will initialize all the attributes with values taken from the `can` definition in Abilities.rb.  However, it will not do anything if those attributes are Arrays, Hashes or Ranges and the default value ends up coming from the schema.

**How can I authorize users to manage posts in their subtree, but when they create a new post, default it to their organization?**

Comment: So I made the following project to test your problem and it is here: https://github.com/robmathews/cancan_test.git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cancan, if the @post variable is already initialized by you, it will not call load_resource on it, only do the authorize part. See this part of the docs: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions, "Override loading".

So the simplest solution is to take control of the initialization yourself and make it what you need, like here:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :initialize_post, :only => [:new, :create]

  def initialize_post
    @post = current_user.organization.posts.build(params[:post]||{:name=>'Smashing Kittens'})
  end

  load_and_authorize_resource :post
  def index
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
  end
end
```

You can see it working in this test project that I created from your post: https://github.com/robmathews/cancan_test.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and ended up writing ancestry related permissions in blocks like so:

```
can :manage, Post do |post|
  post.organization.subtree_ids.include?(user.organization_id)
end
```